# Straight policy on a curved surface in presence of a force field

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Let's assume to have a smooth curved surface with metric tensor $h$ and a stationary force field $f$ on such surface.
Imagine that we now have an overdamped particle moving on it following the equation of motion:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}^k = v_0 e^k + \mu f^k \ ,
\end{equation}
with $\mu$ being the particle mobility, $v_0$ its constant self-propulsion speed and $e^k$ the orientation unit vector, i.e. such that $e_ke^k = 1$.
I would now like to implement a policy for $e^k$ such that the particle points always towards a fixed target on the surface regardless of the force field. I'd call this the "Straight Policy".

I was thinking to use the fact that in absence of the force field, we know that the Riemannian geodesic equation
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^k+\Gamma_{ij}^k\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j=0 \Longrightarrow \dot{e}^k+v_0\Gamma_{ij}^ke^ie^j=0
\end{equation}
corresponds to such policy because in this case the shortest path is also the "straight" one. However, I can't find a consistent way to make use of this to solve the problem.

My best shot so far has been the following. Differentiating the e.o.m. wrt time we get:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^k = v_0\dot{e}^k + \mu\dot{x}^i\partial_i f^k \ ,
\end{equation}
then we can use the Riemannian geodesic solution for $\dot{e}^k$ to get:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}^k = -v_0\Gamma_{ij}^k(\dot{x}^i -\mu f^i)(\dot{x}^j -\mu f^j)+ \mu\dot{x}^i\partial_i f^k \ .
\end{equation}
However, I am pretty sure this is wrong because I have then tried to check that $v_0e^ke_k=(\dot{x}^k -\mu f^k)(\dot{x}_k -\mu f_k)=v_0$ writing a Mathematica code, but turns out this is not the case.

Where am I wrong here? Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi Lorenzo and welcome to PSE! Your question seems to be related more  to control theory rather than general relativity. Even as a control theory problem though , it is not very clear to me.  Perhaps you should move the question to MSE (mathematics stack exchange). They have a control theory section

Comment: Hi @magma, thanks for your suggestion! I'll try to move the question there then.